# log is not writing into file

Tags: python, flask

I want to write log into file. File is creating but nothing is writing into file.
my code is:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
formatter = logging.Formatter("[%(asctime)s] {%(pathname)s:%(lineno)d} %(levelname)s - %(message)s")

handler = RotatingFileHandler('/var/log/httpd/myfile.log', maxBytes=100000, backupCount=10)
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger = logging.getLogger("__init__")
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(handler)

@app.route('/api/urlname', methods=['GET'])
def api_url():
    logger.info("----- REST API is called -----")
    ....
    .....


if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```

When calling **/api/urlname** code is executing and getting result but not see any log in file.
I gave full permission to **myfile.log** like: sudo chmod -R 777 myfile.log.

Can you tell where I did wrong and why log is not writing into file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change both `setLevel(logging.info)` to `setLevel(logging.INFO)` as `logging.info` is a function and `logging.INFO` is the integer (in this case 20) that represents the level of logging for info logging.

Comment: Still I changed setlevel(logging.info) to setlevel(logging.INFO) but still is not working.

Comment: If you use the code above it says `INFo`, the last o should be capital.

Comment: issue is not with spell mistake.

Comment: I see you fixed it now. There is one issue with writing there. Even if you have write permissions to myfile.log, the rotating file handler will eventually log to myfile.log.X where X is a digit. You should transfer ownership of the folder where you want to write to to your user like `chown -R username:group /var/log/httpd` . By the way for debugging I recommend running your code locally and not through Flask.